# Add another secondary key and its respective values to a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, data-wrangling

How do I append another secondary key `Delta` to the dictionary which displays `Width2 - Width` (**2021 values**) and `Width2 - Width` (**2020 values** when Width is **not** available for 2021)?

Dictionary looks as follow:

```
data = {'House1': {'Width': {2021: 0.0},
  'Lenght2': {2021: 0.0, 2020: 0.0},
  'Width2': {2021: 0.0, 2020: 0.0},
  'Length': {2021: 0.0}},
 'House3': {'Height': {2021: 2.40843, 2020: 4.9},
  'Width': {2021: 10.0},
  'Lenght2': {2021: 26.0, 2020: 21.0},
  'Width2': {2021: 50.4, 2020: 86.8},
  'Depth': {2021: 12.0, 2020: 12.0},
  'Length': {2021: 21.88}},
 'House4': {'BI309': {2021: 0.0, 2020: 0.0},
  'Lenght2': {2021: 19.0, 2020: 16.0},
  'Width2': {2021: 100.0, 2020: 100.0},
  'Depth': {2021: 0.0, 2020: 0.0},
  'Width': {2020: 65.0}}}
```

I would like to obtain the following result:

```
data2 = {'House1': {'Width': {2021: 0.0},
  'Lenght2': {2021: 0.0, 2020: 0.0},
  'Width2': {2021: 0.0, 2020: 0.0},
  'Length': {2021: 0.0},
  'Delta': 0.0}},
 'House2': {'Height': {2021: 2.4, 2020: 4.9},
  'Width': {2021: 10.0},
  'Lenght2': {2021: 26.0, 2020: 21.0},
  'Width2': {2021: 50.4, 2020: 86.8},
  'Depth': {2021: 12.0, 2020: 12.0},
  'Length': {2021: 21.88},
  'Delta': 40.4}},
 'House3': {'BI309': {2021: 0.0, 2020: 0.0},
  'Lenght2': {2021: 19.0, 2020: 16.0},
  'Width2': {2021: 100.0, 2020: 90.0},
  'Depth': {2021: 0.0, 2020: 0.0},
  'Width': {2020: 65.0},
  'Delta': 25.0}}
```

Comment: I see you've tagged this as pandas, but you don't have a DataFrame. Are you looking for a pure-python solution, or a pandas solution?

Comment: That was a mistake, pure python solution is what I'm looking for